# Implement class with private constructor in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mocking, stub

I'd like to write a little stub for a service class. The reason is, that I don't want to push the secret API keys that the service class needs to the CI and I don't want the service class in the CI to run against the external service anyways.

However, the service class is non-abstract and has a private constructor.

When I try to create my stub class like:

```
open class FirebaseMock: FirebaseMessaging {
    // implemented functions go here
}
```

it says

> This type has a constructor, and thus must be initialized here

If I try to initialize it like:

```
open class FirebaseMock: FirebaseMessaging() {
    // implemented functions go here
}
```

it goes

> Cannot access '<init>': it is private in 'FirebaseMessaging'

Which is true:

```
private FirebaseMessaging(Builder builder) {
...
```

All I want to do is make my stub class formally a subclass of FirebaseMessaging to use it as placeholder, that mocks the FirebaseMessaging-Functionality when the API keys are not present.
How can I *just implement* a non-abstract, non-interface class, that has a private constructor nonetheless.

My current solution is a wrapper, which works but is not as nice.

Mockito etc. does not seem like a good solution, since this is still in the productive code.

Comment: `My current solution is a wrapper` I was about to suggest just that - why is it not as nice? It makes your design more flexibility since you can change your wrapper's API at will, whereas you can't change `FirebaseMessaging`. There's many benefits in preferring composition over inheritance.

Comment: With inheritance the child just inherits all the parents functionality and I only have to implement those functions whose behaviour I like to change.